# Does Amondi's English accent in Sense8 reflect her wealth?

Tags: character, analysis, realism, casting, sense8

Disclaimer: Spoilers within for Season 1 Episode 6 of Sense8.

In Netflix's show Sense8, Capheus is charged with transporting Kenyan crime lord Silas Kabaka's daughter Amondi to a treatment clinic for leukemia. When the viewers first encounter Amondi, we're a bit surprised to notice she speaks with an English accent despite all signs indicating she was born and raised in Kenya. I'd imagine this was very intentionally chosen as an aspect of the character, even if it is never discussed within the show, but why?

My best guess is that it reflects the fact that she grew up in the very wealthy household of her father, and so was sent to private school where, among other things, she was taught "proper" English. I myself know comparatively little about Kenyan culture, so it's quite possible there's another reason for this, but am I right in assuming that Amondi's English accent is reflective of her being taught in private school due to her wealth?

Comment: I don't remember the show or character specifically, but it is reasonably common for offspring of wealthy parents in countries where English is an official language [or sometimes not even official, such as some middle eastern countries], to actually be educated at private school in the UK itself.